# Unchecked runtime.lastError while running contextMenus.create: Cannot create item with duplicate id

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I got this error message:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running contextMenus.create: Cannot create 
item with duplicate id Korean TTS by Korean Lab
```

Why does it occur?

[image]

Comment: Simply add a callback like `() => chrome.runtime.lastError` to ignore the error.

Comment: Is it a meaningless error? Is it alright to ignore?

Comment: Yes, it is meaningless in this case.